# How to get terminal size in Windows 10 (with PHP)

Tags: php

I know that it's possible to get the terminal size on Linux using the following :

```
$cols = `tput cols`;
$lines = `tput lines`;
```

But on windows, the only solution I found is the following: using the command `mode con`. The problem with this is that I can't even parse it because it's translated and depending on the language of the OS.

So my question is simple: how to get terminal size on windows programmatically with PHP?

Comment: This question has a nothing to do with coding, especially not PHP. It would be better off at https://superuser.com

Comment: Right click on the terminal window->properties ... the size (width + height) can be found there

Comment: @aynber Sorry, the formatting was not great due to the character used. But my point is to get it inside my code, I know I can get it another way. I actually specified it if you read the entire post.

Comment: _“can't even parse it because it's translated and depending on the language of the OS”_ - does the structure of the output change, or just the labels? I would assume that it is probably the latter, so the values for rows and columns should come in the same order. With a regular expression that matches the `TEXT: [whitespace] INTEGER` line format, that should not be to difficult to extract. (Dunno, if you have to take into account RTL systems as well, it might get more complex.)

Comment: @Nek Ah, gotcha. Yeah, since the code formatting wasn't there, I didn't see it was PHP. However, since you're trying to use OS-dependent command-line utilities (`tput` being a linux program, not a PHP command), they still might be able to tell you which command-line program could get you the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v5.2.1/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Terminal.php for the implementation of such retrieval in the Symfony framework. It does not only parse the `mode CON` output but also tries using the `ANSICON` env variable to support the ANSICON terminal. The parsing of the `mode CON` output itself is around line 135 of the file.

Answer (score 0):

try this code. you may get cols and lines.

```
<?php
exec("tput cols", $_cols);
$cols = $_cols[0];
exec("tput lines", $_lines);
$lines = $_lines[0];

echo $cols . " : " . $lines . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: This will not work under windows. (without WSL)